# How do I create a list of dictionaries with same keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Let's say I got three lists below:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]           # five ints
list_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] # five strs
list_3 = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5] # five floats
```

How can combine these three lists to this:

```
[
    {'int': 1, 'str': 'a', 'float': 1.1}, 
    {'int': 2, 'str': 'b', 'float': 2.2}, 
    {'int': 3, 'str': 'c', 'float': 3.3}, 
    {'int': 4, 'str': 'd', 'float': 4.4}, 
    {'int': 5, 'str': 'e', 'float': 5.5}
]
```

What is the syntactically cleanest way to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 17):

```
dct = [{'int':a,'str':b,'float':c}  for a,b,c in zip(list_1,list_2,list_3)]
```

Answer (score 9):

Try using `zip()`.

It basically iterates through
`[(1, 'a', 1.1), (2, 'b', 2.2), (3, 'c', 3.3), (4, 'd', 4.4), (5, 'e', 5.5)]`,
pairs this with your keys `["int","str","float"]` and creates a list of dictionaries with this.

*compact*

```
dictList = [{k:v for k,v in zip(['int','str','float'],pair)} for pair in zip(list_1,list_2,list_3)]
```

*readable for the human eye*

```
dictList = []
for pair in zip(list_1,list_2,list_3):
    dicts1 = {}
    for k,v in zip(['int','str','float'],pair):
        dicts1[k] = v
    dictList.append(dicts1)
```

*hardcoded a tad bit*

```
dictList = [{'int':x,'str':y,'float':z} for x,y,z in zip(list_1,list_2,list_3)]
```

*output*

```
[
    {'int': 1, 'str': 'a', 'float': 1.1}, 
    {'int': 2, 'str': 'b', 'float': 2.2}, 
    {'int': 3, 'str': 'c', 'float': 3.3}, 
    {'int': 4, 'str': 'd', 'float': 4.4}, 
    {'int': 5, 'str': 'e', 'float': 5.5}
]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to @Tim Roberts solution, but allows for arbitrary typing.

```
[dict(((type(x).__name__,x) for x in (a,b,c))) for a,b,c in zip(list_1,list_2,list_3)]
```